# Two rows in a DIV, one with fixed height and another with fluid height

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV like below

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="fixedHt"></div>
    <div class="fluidHt"></div>
</div>
```

I have written CSS like below

```
.fixedHt{
     height:30px;
}
.fluidHt{
     margin-top:30px;
}
```

I want to achieve the same with columns I can achieve with floats, how can I achieve this in rows?

Comment: U mean display:inline-block; ?

Comment: No, first DIV should take fixed height and next DIV should occupy the rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For browsers who support CSS3, use **calc** function (no need for absolute positioning):

see this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/dn2zt/1/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="fixedHt"></div>
    <div class="fluidHt"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}
.fixedHt
{
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
.fluidHt
{
    height: calc(100% - 30px);
    background-color: blue;
}
```

*Tested on*: IE10, IE10 using IE9 mode, FF, Chrome

**Edit:**

CSS3 is not supported in IE8, so instead you can use `height: 270px;` in the `.fluidHt` rule (that is only if the fixed height is not a problem for you) like this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/dn2zt/2/) *[Works with all Broswers]*,

or you can apply a Script that fix the second div's height dynamically. like this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/dn2zt/4/) *[Works with all Broswers]*

Answer (score 4):

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/dn2zt/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="fixedHt small"></div>
    <div class="fluidHt streched"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.streched {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: @Exception Works on my IE8

Comment: Dont work on IE8/IE9 Mode on IE10 (I dont acctualy have IE8, so this is the only way I can test this)

Comment: I tried it also on IE8 Mode on IE10 and it's working. Can you make a print screen?

Comment: I'm sorry. Acttualy it was my mistake. the document mode was not set correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I write here another answer, that don't use calc() and don't relay on the fixed height of the first div, so even if it's height is changing, the second will always span the rest of the container.
also: it has better browser support (IE8+ & all major browsers), and its Pure CSS.

Check this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/dn2zt/5/)

**HTML:** (same)

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="fixedHt"></div>
    <div class="fluidHt"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.parent
{
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    border: 3px solid #000;
}
.parent:before
{
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.fixedHt
{
    height: 30px; /*can be any height*/
    background-color: red;
}
.fluidHt
{
    background-color: blue;
}
.fluidHt:after
{
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
```